# Swift JSON to Flutter JSON

Tags: json, swift, flutter

So In Swift I do this:

```
struct Sdata: Codable {
    var data: [Station]
}

struct Station: Codable , Identifiable  {
  var id,name,imageurl,listenlive:String

  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case id = "_id", name , imageurl , listenlive
  }
}
```

But I am wondering in flutter how is this structured?

As the example:

```
class Photo {
  final int albumId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  Photo({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Photo(
      albumId: json['albumId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

is not really helpful as it does not do a sub-array.

I have tried:

```
class Radata{
  Source data;

  Radata(
    {
     this.data
    }
    );
  factory Radata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            return Radata(
            data: Radio.fromJson(json["data"])
            );
  }
}

class Radio {
  String id;
  String name;
  String imageurl;

  Radio({this.id, this.name, this.imageurl});

  factory Radio.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Radio(
      id: json["_id"] as String,
      name: json["name"] as String,
      imageurl: json["imageurl"] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

But get `Error: 'Source' isn't a type.`
It's for this url https://api.drn1.com.au/station/allstations

I tried the code below - as I need to intergrate it into my current app.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_radio_player/flutter_radio_player.dart';
import './screens/trackswidget.dart';
import 'about_widget.dart';
import './model/photos.dart';




/* TO FETCH PHOTOS */
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
  //await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  await client.get('https://api.drn1.com.au/station/allstations');
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);



}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}



class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
      ),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Image.network(photos[index].thumbnailUrl);
      },
    );
  }
}

/*END FETCH PHOTOS*/

class Radata {
  Radata({
    this.data,
  });

  List<Radio> data;

  factory Radata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Radata(
    data: List<Radio>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Radio.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Radio {
  Radio({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.imageurl,
    this.website,
    this.listenlive,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String imageurl;
  String website;
  String listenlive;

  factory Radio.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Radio(
    id: json["_id"],
    name: json["name"],
    imageurl: json["imageurl"],
    website: json["website"],
    listenlive: json["listenlive"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "_id": id,
    "name": name,
    "imageurl": imageurl,
    "website": website,
    "listenlive": listenlive,
  };
}

Radata radataFromJson(String str) => Radata.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String radataToJson(Radata data) => json.encode(data.toJson());











class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  var playerState = FlutterRadioPlayer.flutter_radio_paused;

  var volume = 0.8;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  bool check = true;
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  FlutterRadioPlayer _flutterRadioPlayer = new FlutterRadioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getHttp();
    super.initState();
    initRadioService();
  }


  Future<void> initRadioService() async {
    try {
      await _flutterRadioPlayer.init(
          "DRN1", "Live", "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream", "true");
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Exception occurred while trying to register the services.");
    }
    //await _flutterRadioPlayer.play();
  }

  Future<void> changestation(e) async{
    try {
      await _flutterRadioPlayer.setUrl(e, "true");
    //  await _flutterRadioPlayer.play();
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Exception occurred while trying to register the services.");
    }
  }

  /* RADIO STATIONS */
  Future<Radata> _future;

  Future<Radata> getHttp() async {
    http.Response response =
    await http.get("https://api.drn1.com.au/station/allstations");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return radataFromJson(response.body);
    }
  }
  /* end radio stations */

  final List<Widget> _children = [TracksWidget(),
    AboutWidget()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text('DRN',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0),),
              const Text('1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 40.0),)
            ],
        ),
      ),
      //body: _children[_currentIndex],
      body:
     Column(
          children: [ SizedBox(
                      height:200,
                      child:ListView(
                        // This next line does the trick.
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: new RaisedButton(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                color: Colors.red,
                                onPressed: () async {  await changestation('http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8006/stream');
                                },

                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                  imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x200",
                                  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                                ),
                              ),

                            ),
                           GestureDetector(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 200,
                                  height:200,
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x200",
                                    placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap:() async {  await changestation('http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8015/stream');}
                              ),
                              /*child: new RaisedButton(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                  onPressed: () async {  await changestation('http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8015/stream');
                                                  },

                                                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                                      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x200",
                                                      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                                                    ),
                                                ),
*/
                            Container(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                      ],
                    ),
                ),

            Expanded(
              child:  FutureBuilder(
                  future: _future,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Radata> snapshot) {
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                      case ConnectionState.none:
                        return Text('none');
                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      case ConnectionState.active:
                        return Text('');
                      case ConnectionState.done:
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text(
                            '${snapshot.error}',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Card(
                                    elevation: 6.0,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 6.0,
                                          bottom: 6.0,
                                          left: 8.0,
                                          right: 8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(snapshot.data.data[index].name
                                              .toString()),
                                          Spacer(),
                                          Text(
                                            snapshot.data.data[index].id,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ));
                              });
                        }
                    }
                  }),
                ),

              Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () async {  await changestation('http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8015/stream');
                    },

                    child: new Text("Change Station"),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('Craft beautiful UIs', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.contain, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
                    child: const FlutterLogo(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

    ]),

      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 80.0,
        width: 80.0,
        child: FittedBox(
          child:FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                    setState((){
                      if(check)
                      {
                        check = false;
                         _flutterRadioPlayer.play();
                        print("false");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        check = true;
                         _flutterRadioPlayer.pause();
                        print("true");
                      }

                    }),
                    },
         child: Icon(check ? Icons.play_arrow: Icons.pause),
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                mini: true,
              ),
        ),

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          decoration:
          new BoxDecoration(color: new Color(0xFFFF0000)),
          height: 75,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {

                    onTabTapped(0);
                  });
                },
              ),
          /*    IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    onTabTapped(1);
                  });
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    onTabTapped(2);
                  });
                },
              ),*/
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    onTabTapped(1);
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),// new

    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

and I  keep getting none printing out.

Comment: This is a [post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) I usually look up for json to dart conversion step by step. For easy and fast conversion, [this tool](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) does the job for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Radata radataFromJson(String str) => Radata.fromJson(json.decode(str));` 
You can see full code for `class Radata` and `class Radio` 
code snippet

```
Radata radataFromJson(String str) => Radata.fromJson(json.decode(str));
...
Future<Radata> getHttp() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get("https://api.drn1.com.au/station/allstations");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return radataFromJson(response.body);
    }
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final radata = radataFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Radata radataFromJson(String str) => Radata.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String radataToJson(Radata data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Radata {
  Radata({
    this.data,
  });

  List<Radio> data;

  factory Radata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Radata(
        data: List<Radio>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Radio.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Radio {
  Radio({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.imageurl,
    this.website,
    this.listenlive,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String imageurl;
  String website;
  String listenlive;

  factory Radio.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Radio(
        id: json["_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        imageurl: json["imageurl"],
        website: json["website"],
        listenlive: json["listenlive"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "name": name,
        "imageurl": imageurl,
        "website": website,
        "listenlive": listenlive,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<Radata> _future;

  Future<Radata> getHttp() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get("https://api.drn1.com.au/station/allstations");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return radataFromJson(response.body);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getHttp();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Radata> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                              elevation: 6.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 6.0,
                                    bottom: 6.0,
                                    left: 8.0,
                                    right: 8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(snapshot.data.data[index].name
                                        .toString()),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data.data[index].id,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

full code 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_radio_player/flutter_radio_player.dart';

Photo photoFromJson(String str) => Photo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String photoToJson(Photo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Photo {
  Photo({
    this.data,
  });

  List<Datum> data;

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Photo(
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.imageurl,
    this.website,
    this.listenlive,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String imageurl;
  String website;
  String listenlive;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        imageurl: json["imageurl"],
        website: json["website"],
        listenlive: json["listenlive"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "name": name,
        "imageurl": imageurl,
        "website": website,
        "listenlive": listenlive,
      };
}

/* TO FETCH PHOTOS */
Future<Photo> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      //await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
      await client.get('https://api.drn1.com.au/station/allstations');
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
Photo parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  return photoFromJson(responseBody);
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final Photo photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
      ),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: photos.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Image.network(photos.data[index].imageurl);
      },
    );
  }
}

/*END FETCH PHOTOS*/

/* RADIO STATIONS */
Radata radataFromJson(String str) => Radata.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String radataToJson(Radata data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Radata {
  Radata({
    this.data,
  });

  List<Radio> data;

  factory Radata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Radata(
        data: List<Radio>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Radio.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Radio {
  Radio({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.imageurl,
    this.website,
    this.listenlive,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String imageurl;
  String website;
  String listenlive;

  factory Radio.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Radio(
        id: json["_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        imageurl: json["imageurl"],
        website: json["website"],
        listenlive: json["listenlive"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "name": name,
        "imageurl": imageurl,
        "website": website,
        "listenlive": listenlive,
      };
}
/* END RADIO STATIONS*/

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  var playerState = FlutterRadioPlayer.flutter_radio_paused;

  var volume = 0.8;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool check = true;
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  FlutterRadioPlayer _flutterRadioPlayer = FlutterRadioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //initRadioService();
  }

  Future<void> initRadioService() async {
    try {
      await _flutterRadioPlayer.init("DRN1", "Live",
          "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream", "true");
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Exception occurred while trying to register the services.");
    }
    //await _flutterRadioPlayer.play();
  }

  Future<void> changestation(e) async {
    try {
      await _flutterRadioPlayer.setUrl(e, "true");
      //  await _flutterRadioPlayer.play();
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Exception occurred while trying to register the services.");
    }
  }

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    Text("TracksWidget()"),
    Text("AboutWidget()")
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'DRN',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0),
            ),
            const Text(
              '1',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 40.0),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      //body: _children[_currentIndex],
      body: Column(children: [
        FutureBuilder<Photo>(
          future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

            return snapshot.hasData
                ? Expanded(child: PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data))
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ]),

/*    body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
                stream: _flutterRadioPlayer.isPlayingStream,
                initialData: widget.playerState,
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                  String returnData = snapshot.data;
                  print("object data: " + returnData);
                  switch (returnData) {
                    case FlutterRadioPlayer.flutter_radio_stopped:
                      return RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Start listening now"),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await initRadioService();
                          });
                      break;
                    case FlutterRadioPlayer.flutter_radio_loading:
                      return Text("Loading stream...");
                    case FlutterRadioPlayer.flutter_radio_error:
                      return RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Retry ?"),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await initRadioService();
                          });
                      break;
                    default:
                      return Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  print("button press data: " +
                                      snapshot.data.toString());
                                  await _flutterRadioPlayer.playOrPause();
                                },
                                icon: snapshot.data ==
                                    FlutterRadioPlayer
                                        .flutter_radio_playing
                                    ? Icon(Icons.pause)
                                    : Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  await _flutterRadioPlayer.stop();
                                },
                                icon: Icon(Icons.stop))
                          ]);
                      break;
                  }
                }),
            Slider(
                value: widget.volume,
                min: 0,
                max: 1.0,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                  widget.volume = value;
                  _flutterRadioPlayer.setVolume(widget.volume);
                })),
            Text("Volume: " + (widget.volume * 100).toStringAsFixed(0))
          ],
        ),
      ),
*/

      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 80.0,
        width: 80.0,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => {
              setState(() {
                if (check) {
                  check = false;
                  _flutterRadioPlayer.play();
                  print("false");
                } else {
                  check = true;
                  _flutterRadioPlayer.pause();
                  print("true");
                }
              }),
            },
            child: Icon(check ? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            mini: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFFFF0000)),
          height: 75,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    onTabTapped(0);
                  });
                },
              ),
              /*    IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    onTabTapped(1);
                  });
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    onTabTapped(2);
                  });
                },
              ),*/
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    onTabTapped(1);
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), //
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

working demo 2

[image]

Comment: Just wondering : any way to make it like this:

```
 FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
                  future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

                    return snapshot.hasData
                        ?  Expanded(child: PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data))
                        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: my full code already contain FutureBuidler. Did you encounter any error?

Comment: I got   return Text('none'); on my screen. - see above I added your code to my app and got an error

Comment: it means ConnectionState.none , you can check response.statusCode. to see if it's internet problem. I can not reproduce in my environment.

Comment: Well my app is loading other data from the internet so are you sure this is not checking a users 4G network - as that is the thing I don't have.

Comment: I have test my full code again. and it works fine. data loaded okay. if you run this in release mode. make sure you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: you can print response.body to see what you got.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223733/discussion-between-russellharrower-and-chunhunghan).

Comment: see full code 2. you need to use Photo not List<Photo> and some image url in not working.